# How to define a "constant" and access it everywhere in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm fiddling a bit with node.js and during my (so called) project I stumbled upon a problem that, although not totally deterrent, annoys the hell out of me.

I work with PHP framework CodeIgniter everyday, and something that CodeIgniter has (and probably any other PHP framework has too) is a way to define once the **BASE URL** and then can be accessed anywhere (libraries, controllers, models, views...) with a simple function. Pretty standard stuff.

Now, in Express I can't find a way to do the same. I wandered through questions on SO from people asking something similar, and usually the answers would be about `res.locals` or `app.locals`, which is not working. I'm using Express 3.1.1 and the **ejs-locals** as a template engine. I know I can define a global variable and then pass it to the render function, but I was wondering if there is a way (that works) to access it everywhere. I believe the problem might be the Template engine, but, it would be nice to have a second opinion.

Thanks.

Comment: app.locals would usually be the place. How is it not working? Can you post your app set-up?

Comment: I define it like `... app.locals.base_url = 'http://192.168.1.71:3000'; ...` and inside the ejs-locals template `var socket = io.connect(<%= base_url %>);` but it just throws a 500 ReferenceError

Comment: Did you assign this before app.listen?

Also, how does the call to render the template look? (ie;res.render('mytemplate',{});)

Does base_url work in the template if you pass it directly like: res.render('mytemplate',{base_url:'http://192.168.1.71:3000'}) ?

Comment: Yes, it is assign in the app.configure. It does work when passed directly, like the other variables. It works normally there. It might be the ejs-locals way of processing the templates.

Comment: I use 'ejs-locals' too and app.locals work fine. The only other thing I can think would be to make sure it's set before your app.router and don't pass another {locals:{}} object in the res.render call.

Comment: How would you use the variable `base_url` assigned like I did, within a template called "chat" rendered as `res.render('chat', { foo : 'bar'})` ?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, there is no `app` variable defined in the template scope.

Comment: I would use just as you have. Strange that it's not working for you.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page, when you say you use the ejs-locals you are refering to this module https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Looking at the Express docs (http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals), have tried using app.set instead?

Comment: Yep, doesn't work either.

Answer (score -2):

in app.js just change this

```
 var myVar = "only in file";
```

with this (without "var")

```
 myVar = "everywhere";
```

It's better if you do it just in case.

Comment: This creates a global variable, which is *highly* frowned upon in node.  Additionally, globals aren't guaranteed to be available *everywhere* (things like the [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) and [contextify](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify) modules allow code to run with their own global object).

Comment: ouh, ok. i didn't know that... :O